# php | Array merge

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 2
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Name 1
            [sku] => Model 1
            [options] => Color: <em>Black (+10$)</em>. Memory: <em>32GB (+99$)</em>. 
            [price] => 209.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Name 1
            [sku] => Model 1
            [options] => Color: <em>Black (+10$)</em>. Memory: <em>16GB</em>. 
            [price] => 110.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Name 2
            [sku] => Model 2
            [options] => 
            [price] => 100.00
        )
)
```

First step is to find the same id. And if the same id exist convert array.
Is it possible to get output array (if id the same remove one and add qty to the another)?

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 3 // 2+1
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Name 1
                [sku] => Model 1
                [options] => Color: <em>Black (+10$)</em>. Memory: <em>32GB (+99$)</em>. 
                [price] => 209.00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 1
                [id] => 3
                [name] => Name 2
                [sku] => Model 2
                [options] => 
                [price] => 100.00
            )
    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: then what about price and options???

Comment: If you don't care about the other attributes, it shouldbe pretty easy with a `foreach` loop. What have you tried and what was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($input as $subarray) {
  $id = $subarray['id'];
  if (isset($result[$id])) { // Same ID
    $result[$id]['qty'] += $subarray['qty']; // Add quantities
  } else {
    $result[$id] = $subarray; // New ID, put in results
  }
}
$result = array_values($result); // Convert from associative array to indexed
```