# Create array nested PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi all' I have a page into PHP where I retrieve XML data from a server and I want to store this data into an array.

This is my code:

```
foreach ($xml->DATA as $entry){
    foreach ($entry->HOTEL_DATA as $entry2){
        $id = (string)$entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;
        $hotel_array2 = array();
        $hotel_array2['id'] = $entry2->ID;
            $hotel_array2['name'] = utf8_decode($entry2->HOTEL_NAME);
        $i=0;
        foreach($entry2->ROOM_DATA as $room){
            $room_array = array();
            $room_array['id'] = (string)$room->attributes()->CCHARGES_CODE;
            $hotel_array2['rooms'][$i] = array($room_array);

            $i++;
        }
            array_push($hotel_array, $hotel_array2);
        }
}
```

In this mode I have the array hotel_array which all hotel with rooms.
The problem is that: into my XML I can have multiple hotel with same ID (the same hotel) with same information but different rooms.
If I have an hotel that I have already inserted into my hotel_array I don't want to insert a new array inside it but I only want to take its rooms array and insert into the exisiting hotel.
Example now my situation is that:

```
hotel_array{
      [0]{
           id = 1,
           name = 'test'
           rooms{
               id = 1
           }
      }
      [0]{
           id = 2,
           name = 'test2'
           rooms{
               id = 100
           }
      }
      [0]{
           id = 1,
           name = 'test'
           rooms{
               id = 30
           }
      }
}
```

I'd like to have this result instead:

```
hotel_array{
      [0]{
           id = 1,
           name = 'test'
           rooms{
               [0]{
                  id = 1
               }
               [1]{
                  id = 30
               }
           }
      }
      [0]{
           id = 2,
           name = 'test2'
           rooms{
               id = 100
           }
      }
}
```

How to create an array like this?

Thanks

Comment: Use an associative array where the id is the key. Then check whether the element already exists, and add the new room to it instead of creating a new element.

Comment: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336004/php-array-merge for a similar problem, where he wanted to add up an element in entries with the same ID.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar thanks I have seen it's another great solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first thing is it helps to keep the hotel id as the index on `hotel_array` when your creating it.

```
foreach ($xml->DATA as $entry){
    foreach ($entry->HOTEL_DATA as $entry2){
        $id = (string)$entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;
        $hotel_array2 = array();
        $hotel_array2['id'] = $entry2->ID;
            $hotel_array2['name'] = utf8_decode($entry2->HOTEL_NAME);
        $i=0;
        foreach($entry2->ROOM_DATA as $room){
            $room_array = array();
            $room_array['id'] = (string)$room->attributes()->CCHARGES_CODE;
            $hotel_array2['rooms'][$i] = array($room_array);

            $i++;
        }
            if (!isset($hotel_array[$hotel_array2['id']])) {
                  $hotel_array[$hotel_array2['id']] = $hotel_array2;
            } else {
                  $hotel_array[$hotel_array2['id']]['rooms'] = array_merge($hotel_array[$hotel_array2['id']]['rooms'], $hotel_array2['rooms']);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this is the similar answer to DevZer0 (+1), there is also quite a bit that can be done to simplify your workings... there is no need to use `array_merge` for one, or be specific about `$i` within your rooms array.

```
$hotels = array();
foreach ($xml->DATA as $entry){
  foreach ($entry->HOTEL_DATA as $entry2){
    $id = (string) $entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;
    if ( empty($hotels[$id]) ) {
      $hotels[$id] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => utf8_decode($entry2->HOTEL_NAME),
        'rooms' => array(),
      );
    }
    foreach($entry2->ROOM_DATA as $room){
      $hotels[$id]['rooms'][] = array(
        'id' => (string) $room->attributes()->CCHARGES_CODE;
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Just in case it helps...

Comment: it can be more quickly than array_merge?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri - No worries. With regard to `array_merge` I was just meaning if you built your array as you went, rather than constructing separate arrays (which you then have to merge) it would be more optimal. But then there are always a number of ways to achive the same result :)

Comment: Yeah and works fine I have accepted the other answer but this is another good solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

And this :)

```
$hotel_array = array();

foreach ($xml->DATA as $entry)
{
    foreach ($entry->HOTEL_DATA as $entry2)
    {
        $hotel_code = (string) $entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;

        if (false === isset($hotel_array[$hotel_code]))
        {
            $hotel = array(
                'id' => $entry2->ID,
                'code' => $hotel_code,
                'name' => utf8_decode($entry2->HOTEL_NAME)
            );

            foreach($entry2->ROOM_DATA as $room)
            {
                $hotel['rooms'][] = array(
                    'id' => (string)$room->attributes()->CCHARGES_CODE,
                );
            }

            $hotel_array[$hotel_code] = $hotel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know there is a logic error in your code. Your `if` statement would mean subsequent hotels (that are repeated) would not have their rooms added. You'd need to move the rooms `foreach` outside the `if`, then it should work :)

Comment: 10x :) But without initial xml data it's hard to say. My version just for more simple logic illustration.